# Plot and DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I'm working on this code to modify it but I can't plot it and solve the second part?!!

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {y[x]^2 - Sqrt[3] (a/b) y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 - k x^-2 - f] - k (1 - 2/(3 b))x^-2 -f == 0}; 
sol =FullSimplify[Solve[eqns, y[x]], Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, k > 0, f > 0}]
a = 1; b = 0.24; f = 0.68; k = 0.002;
Plot[sol[[1]], {a, 0, 10}]
y1[x_] = y[x] /. sol
DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t]
```

Comment: You are right a = 1; b = 0.24; f = 0.68; k = 0.002; but still is not working!!

Comment: First of all, **eqns is not a differential equation**!

Comment: First one no but the second one yes

Comment: You should not use `DSolve` on `eqns`.

Comment: I fixed that part, now next part isn't working

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706, and look carefully at how solutions are used in the documentation for `DSolve`, `Solve`, `NDSolve`.... They return sets of `Rule[]` objects, and usually users want to deal with scalar numeric expressions -- certainly for `Plot`. You need to convert your solutions to such expressions or use `DSolveValue`, `SolveValues` [sic], `NDSolveValue`....

Answer (score 4):

> now next part isn't working

If you go step by step, it will become more clear. I assume this is what you wanted. This is for one solution from `Solve` for illustration, as there are 4 solutions. You can do the same for the other 3 solutions. You also need to change `x` to `x[t]` to make an ode. Also it is better to use exact numbers with `DSolve`. Also the first plot should be w.r.t. `x` and not `a` since `a` is a number.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {y[x]^2 - Sqrt[3] (a/b) y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 - k x^-2 - f] - 
     k (1 - 2/(3 b)) x^-2 - f == 0};
a = 1; b = 24/100; f = 68/100; k = 2/1000;
(*use first solution for now *)
sol = y[x] /. First@FullSimplify[Solve[eqns, y[x]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[Abs@sol, {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
y1 = sol /. x -> x[t]
ode = y1 == x'[t]/x[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this ode can't be solved exactly (it is non linear) and the solution has an integral that can not be solved

```
DSolve[ode, x[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might want to use `NDSolve` instead.